# Picasso 2.7. Как очистить кэш?

Tags: java, android, picasso

Приложение загружает в RecyclerView много изображений из сети с помощью Picasso, версия 2.71828. Иногда изображение не прогружается полностью и как его не обновляй, снизу остается белый непрогруженный кусок. Насколько я понимаю, происходит это из-за того, что Picasso достает однажды загруженные изображения из кэша. Пытался очистить кэш таким образом `Picasso.get().invalidate(imageUrl)`, но ничего не получилось.
В сети по этому поводу в основном советуют использовать `Picasso.with(context).cache.clear()`, но похоже, что в новых версиях библиотеки уже нет метода `.with(context)`. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Пардон, это просто картинки бракованные попадались:) Кэш чистится и так `Picasso.get().invalidate(imageUrl)`, и вот так сразу весь:

```
package com.squareup.picasso;

    public class PicassoTools {

        public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
            p.cache.clear();
        }
    }
    --------------------------------------
    PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.get());
```